# Regex - Replace a code by a link

Tags: c#, regex, expression, substring

I need to replace an expression in text, like this example:

testA **M123456** testB
Result = testA **www.test.com** testB

This string whith 1 char M followed by 6 digits, represents a code to be replaced by a hyperlink.

Please help me, using regex to solve this problem

Comment: I forgot to answer you, but thanks. The solution works fine

Answer (score 3):

this should do it

```
string Result = Regex.Replace("estA M123456 testB", "M[0-9]{6}", "www.test.com");
```

the pattern is `M[0-9]{6}` - a `M` followed by 6 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `MatchEvaluator` to translate the links depending on the number, like so:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> knownLinks = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
  {123456, "www.test.com"},
  {999999, "www.foo.com"},
};

private static string LinkReplacer(Match match)
{
  int linkNumber = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
  string link = knownLinks[linkNumber];
  return link;
}

public static void Replace()
{
  string text = "testA M123456 testB Result M999999 testC";
  string replacedText = Regex.Replace(text, "M([0-9]{6})", LinkReplacer);

  Console.WriteLine(replacedText);
}


// output: testA www.test.com testB Result www.foo.com testC
```

Some explanations:

- We first create a LinkReplacer function that tells us how to look up the link for a given number. Then we pass our LinkReplacer function to Regex.Replace to be used as MatchEvaluator. This means that Regex.Replace will now forward every found instance to that method and retrieve the replacement string from there.
- The () brackets in the pattern `M([0-9]{6})` tell Regex that this is a "Group". In the LinkReplacer, you can see that we then access this Group to retrieve the content. (We also could just remove the first letter of the whole match, which is always an 'M'.)
- The dictionary is just for the example; I assume you have a database somewhere to retrieve the correct links from.
- The example text is a bit longer to test that all occurrences are replaced and not just the first, and that the replacement string is calculated for each separately.

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry, i forgot to answer. The solution works fine...thanks